# Read the PNG image as NSData, and some extra bytes appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, png

[image]

Above is the data to read the picture using iOS SDK,
00000004 43674249 50002006 2cb87766
are extra bytes.
Does anyone know what these bytes are?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not a standard PNG according to [the official specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG). The bytes you point out form a valid [PNG chunk](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5Chunk-layout):

```
00000004 Data length
43674249 Block ID "CgBI"
50002006 4 bytes of proprietary information
2CB87766 CRC checksum of the data block
```

but the location and the indicated type of the chunk are invalid for a conforming PNG image.
This indicates the image is processed with Apple's modified version of `pngcrush`. See http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format#Differences_from_PNG for non-official information on the block contents and other deviations from the official specification.

Comment: Thank you, This question has been bothering me for some time